# How to print an array of characters in swift without a line terminator

Tags: swift, string, printing, character, swift-playground

This should be simple to solve. When I try printing an array of characters in a Swift playground, I see each character printed with a end of line terminator...

For Example when I type this in a Swift Playground.

```
var strTokenizeMe = "Go Pro"

for chrInStr in strTokenizeMe { print(chrInStr,"*")}
```

This prints

```
G
o

P
r
o
```

Now I do NOT want and end of line terminator, so I add terminator: " " at the end of the print statement, like this ...

```
for chrInStr in strTokenizeMe { print(chrInStr, terminator: " ")}
```

But when I do this NOTHING gets printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a *Playground* you need to print one final newline, otherwise the output
is not flushed to the output window:

```
for chrInStr in strTokenizeMe { print(chrInStr, terminator: " ")}
print()
```

A (not necessarily better) alternative would be to concatenate
the characters *before* printing them:

```
print(strTokenizeMe.map(String.init).joined(separator: " "))
```

The problem does not occur when running a compiled program, because
the standard output is always flushed on program exit.